# Map signature mismatch with Whatever? x vs X vs xx

Tags: raku

The last line here results in a incorrect signature to the map call:

```
my @array=[0,1,2];
say "String Repetition";
say @array.map({($_ x 2)});
say @array.map: * x 2;

say "\nCross product ";
say @array.map({($_ X 2)});
say @array.map: * X 2;

say "\nList Repetition";
say @array.map({$_ xx 2});
say @array.map: * xx 2;
```

The output being:

```
String Repetition
(00 11 22)
(00 11 22)

Cross product 
(((0 2)) ((1 2)) ((2 2)))
(((0 2)) ((1 2)) ((2 2)))

List Repetition
((0 0) (1 1) (2 2))
Cannot resolve caller map(Array:D: Seq:D); none of these signatures match:
    ($: Hash \h, *%_)
    (\SELF: &block;; :$label, :$item, *%_)
```

The x operator returns a Str, the X returns a List of Lists and the xx return a List.

Is this changed somehow using the Whatever. Why is this error happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: "`xx` return a `List`" Not quite. This is a tiny point, and one of Lizmat's comment on JJ's answer hints at it, but I thought it useful to leave this comment here too. P6ers distinguish "list", which generically means a list of things, including, eg. arrays, and `List`, which is a particular data type. `xx` returns a "list" (all lowercase) but it's not a [`List`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/List) or a sub-class of `List`. Instead `xx` returns a [`Seq`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Seq). A `Seq` is a *list* but it's not a `List` or a sub-class of `List`. (Thus `say Seq ~~ List` returns `False`.)

Comment: I get the difference. Thanks for the clarification and pointing it out.  The documentation however does indicate it returns a  List https://docs.perl6.org/routine/xx  and also https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_xx. Running `( 1 xx 2).^name` does indeed show a Seq.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. And thanks also to, respectively, drclaw1394 (you?), and JJ, who opened a ticket about this, and fixed the docs, while I was asleep. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me see if I can get this through clearly. If I don't, please ask.

Short answer: `xx` has a special meaning together with `Whatever`, so it's not creating a `WhateverCode` as in the rest of the examples.

Let's see if I can get this straight with the long answer.

First, definitions. * is called [`Whatever`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Whatever). It's generally used in situations in which it's *curried*

> I'm not too happy with this name, which points at functional-language-currying, but does not seem to be used in that sense, but in the sense of *stewing* or *baking*. Anyway.

Currying it turns it into [`WhateverCode`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/WhateverCode). So an * by itself is Whatever, * with some stuff is WhateverCode, creating a block out of thin air.

However, that does not happen automatically, because some times we need Whatever just be Whatever. You have a few exceptions [listed on `Whatever` documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Whatever). One of them is using `xx`, because `xx` together with `Whatever` should create infinite lists.

But that's not what I'm doing, you can say. `*` is *in front of* the number to multiply. Well, yes. But [this code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/f473216452875f10232c86c5e6f9de217619245d/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L9602) in Actions.nqp (which generates code from the source) refers to *infix* `xx`. So it does not really matter.

So, back to the short answer: you can't *always* use `*` together with other elements to create code. Some operators, such as that one, .. or ... will have special meaning in the proximity of *, so you'll need to use something else, like placeholder arguments.

Comment: The special cases in the Whatever documentation  shows `1 xx *` as an example of when the * will remain a Whatever. However in my case I'm using it with arguments swapped the other way around  `* xx 2`. Without diving deeply the NQP code (I'm pretty new to Perl6 let alone NQP ) perhaps the special case list seems only to care about the operator (xx) and not its arguments? Thanks for the response. Lots of code to read over.. eventually :)

Comment: @RubenWesterberg it does. It does not look at routine signature, just at the routine itself, as I said above. It was an excellent question, Keep them coming :-)

Comment: The problem, if you will, is that infix `xx` takes its left-hand side **literally**.  So `* xx 2` is really `(*,*).Seq`.  And `* xx *` is an infinite `Seq` of `*` (aka `Whatever`). The decision as to why `* xx ...` doesn't curry, is lost in the mists of time to me.

Answer (score 7):

The `xx` operator is “thunky”.

```perl6
say( rand xx 2 );
# (0.7080396712923503 0.3938678220039854)
```

Notice that `rand` got executed twice. `x` and `X` don't do that.

```perl6
say( rand x 2 );
0.133525574759261740.13352557475926174

say( rand X 1,2 );
((0.2969453468495996 1) (0.2969453468495996 2))
```

That is `xx` sees each side as something sort of like a lambda on their own.
(A “thunk”)

```perl6
say (* + 1 xx 2);
# ({ ... } { ... })

say (* + 1 xx 2)».(5);
# (6 6)
```

So you get a sequence of `*` repeated twice.

```perl6
say (* xx 2).map: {.^name}
# (Whatever Whatever)
```

(The term `*`, is an instance of Whatever)

---

This also means that you can't create a WhateverCode closure with `&&` / `and`, `||` / `or`, `^^` / `xor`, or `//`.

```perl6
say (* && 1);
# 1
```

---

Note that `*` also does something different on the right side of `xx`.
It creates an infinite sequence.

```perl6
say ( 2 xx * ).head(20);
# (2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)
```

If `xx` wasn't “thunky”, then this would also have created a WhateverCode lambda.

Comment: "thunky".... interesting name!  I just tried `rand X 2` which does give two different values, so does this not make X 'thunky' as well? Cheers

Comment: @RubenWesterberg No, `X` is not thunky. There is a reason I had two values on the right side of `X` in my example. It was so that the left side got repeated twice. If there is only one value on the right, the left value only gets repeated once. Try it with `rand X 42`.